# is there a way to update filter with async data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-filter

I had build the next angular filter:

```
App.filter('cur2symbol', ['CurrenciesService', function (CurrenciesService) {
        return function (input, iso) {
            input = input || '';
            iso = iso || 'ILS';
            var symbol= CurrenciesService.getCurrencySymbolByIso(iso);

            return symbol+input;
        };
    }])
```

the meaning of this filter is to get currency iso code and convert is to symbol for examle:
the next code `{{200|cur2symbol:"ILS"}}` will output `₪200`.

My problem is that the **CurrenciesService** service is Async, so the filter is not working correctly.
only filtering After the the service load are getting the symbol.

I thought about the next solutions:
 1. Instead of using filter, using directive and making the symbol a Model, so it will update when the data is loaded. the problem is it will create too much bindings, I am using the currency symbol in many places!.
 2. finding a way to run the filter again after the service has loaded (I don't know if it's even possible)

I will be glad for any ideas solution