# how to make angular directive accept string or model respectively

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create an angular directive that will be able to get BOTH model object and a string.
if the directive get a string it just output HTML, but if it's a model the the directive will watch the model for changes and will output data respectively.

I had tried to use the next code:

```
App.directive('iso2symbol', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var curIsoObj = $scope.$eval($attrs.curIso);
            //this is object it may change
            if (typeof curIsoObj !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('not a text');
                $scope.$watch('curIso', function (value) {
                   console.log(value);
                });
            }
        },
        template: '<span>{{currencySymbol}}</span>'
    }
}]);
```

This is not working, I had googled it for long time and I don't find the problem....

here is a link to JSfiddle where I had set a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sqrkh7mn/10/)

Comment: Is this really the best way to tackle things? What if you come to a case where it's suppose to be a string but you have a model object with the same string?  Your code will not interpret it as a string and it will not work properly then you will spend hours debugging it.

Comment: This directive should act as a filter...
I can't use a filter here for [various reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841486/is-there-a-way-to-update-filter-with-async-data), so I need it to accept any data type.

Answer (score 0):

Becareful with what you're watching.

according to your watch function you're watching $scope.curIso which really isn't a scope object.

you should be watching

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.$eval($attrs.curIso);}, function (value) {
    $scope.txt = value;
});
```

Comment: Just beware you test the string version/model object version in the same controller since you're referring to $scope.txt which by changing it in one directive will change it in all other directives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
App.directive('iso2symbol', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            curIso: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$observe('curIso', function(newValue, oldValue){
                var curIsoObj = newValue;
                // Do your test now to see if it's undefined,
                // a string, or generic object.
                // (the first time it will likely be undefined)
            }
        },
        template: '<span>{{currencySymbol}}</span>'
    }
}]);
```